# Is it an access Bug? my problem with form filtering by txtBox entered value in a split DB

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have an Access 2016 DB 64bits contain related tables with a search split form that have an txtBox that filtered records accoring to its entered value.
Every thing is just fine with that for months and with thousands of records.
When I want to make it more proffesional to deploy it to other users by re-writing another similar DB but with 32bts Access 2016 and SPLIT it from the start into Tables Back-end and a Front end, the search form didn't show any record when I fire a searching parameter in the after update event!

the search form is linked to a query, I change it to a new one, also try to link the form directly to only one table for testing also not goes right, shows zero results.
when remove the filter, all records showing up again.

when I change the filter directly from the form properties it also fail for string search but when search for a primary key in a form control holding it its working just fine. ( search for Strings show no results, search for Numbers ( ex ID value, show correct results).
And Very strange, when I build another new DB (Same access application) just for testing for what is going on, with a form and joined to split back end tables and a textbox in the form to enter keywords to show the all related records in the that split form, it works fine, both for strings and for numbers?

```
Private Sub txtSearch_AfterUpdate()

Dim strFilter As String

    On Error Resume Next

    If Me.txtSearch.Text <> "" Then

        strFilter = "[Complaints] Like '*" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "*'"
        Me.Filter = strFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.Filter = ""
        Me.FilterOn = False
    End If
    With Me.txtSearch
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = Len(Me.txtSearch.Text)
    End With

End Sub
```

when put a string into the txtsearch box , the code must search for any string with in [Complaints] similar to it and shows the records holding it.

with me it works in the old DB 64bits Not splitted,  but its not working for the new DB 32bits split to back and front ends.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using `.Text` as it requires the control to have focus. So try:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strFilter As String

    ' On Error Resume Next       ' Don't use while debugging.

    If Nz(Me!txtSearch.Value) <> "" Then
        strFilter = "[Complaints] Like '*" & Me!txtSearch.Value & "*'"
        Me.Filter = strFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.Filter = ""
        Me.FilterOn = False
    End If
    With Me!txtSearch
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = Len(.Value)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Gustav, I tried your suggestion, chaned to .value instead of .text, But still NOT WORKING.

Comment: If it works with a new db other than the current, then something else is going on, which we cannot see.